# Em expressões regulares no .htaccess, o que significa essa regra?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

O que está regra está fazendo exatamente?

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com\.br$   
 RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
```

Comment: Acho que ele seta a base da URL, no seu caso, para `/` quando o domínio for aquele da condição

Comment: Mas daí não seria `RewriteBase /`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linha do `RewriteCond` é uma condição para a execução da próxima linha

A linha do `RewriteRule` cria uma variável com o nome `REWRITEBASE` e valor `/`, você pode acessar ela usando `%{ENV:REWRITEBASE}`. Exemplo de uso:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com\.br$   
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/website]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?other\.com\.br$   
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/other]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}/$1
```

Dessa forma você pode dividir a hospedagem em pastas para cada domínio registrado